# In production Django {{object.image.url}} not working in production. How to show image/MEDIA_ROOT/ in production?

Tags: django

When I set `DEBUG=False` in app/settings.py

`{{object.img.url}}` not working. How to fix this?

when I inspect it's `img.url` getting `/images/image_name.jpg`  like this. In `DEBUG=True` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/image_name.jpg` it shows image. But when I set `DEBUG=False` this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/image_name.jpg` this didn't show anything.

my media root

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'static/images')
```

in my URL I added

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

How to show image/MEDIA_ROOT/ in production.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As django doc says, it is:

> Helper function to return a URL pattern for serving files in **debug**
> mode:
> See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#module-django.conf.urls). So, this function returns no URL patterns if not in `DEBUG` mode.

In general, as a rule of thumb, Django should not serve static content, i.e. `static` or `media` files. Some other, like nginx, apache, etc. should serve static content in production environment.

Comment: Thanks. {% static  object.img.url %} seems working.

Answer (score 1):

Following 4 settings are important.

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "https://xyz.abc.com/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = "/home/kcsl/web/xyz.abc.com/public_html/static/"

MEDIA_URL = "https://xyz.abc.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/kcsl/web/xyz.abc.com/public_html/media/"
```

Use collectstatic command also

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```