# Django - PDF file not uploading but path is available

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-models

I'm trying to upload a pdf file to the database with forms but however the file isn't send to the server.

models.py

```
class Presse(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField()
```

forms.py

```
class PresseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Presse
        fields = '__all__'
```

I tried same way I do when uploading images, which works fine. Somewhere I have an error or forgot something I didn't know about.
views.py

```
def presse(request):
    article = Presse.objects.get(id=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PresseForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            redirect('main:presse')
    else:
        form = PresseForm(instance=article)
    return render(request, 'main/presse.html', {
        'article': article,
        'form': form
    })
```

presse.html

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-success">Ersetzen & speichern</button>
    </form>
```

If I upload a file after getting redirected I get error 404

**GET http://localhost:8000/media/Untitled.pdf 404 (Not Found)**

The path is correct but the file wasn't served.
Do you have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Have you configured your urls to serve the uploaded files? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Please see [this one](
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407082/in-production-django-object-image-url-not-working-in-production-how-to-show/67407375#67407375)! MEDIA_URL AND MEDIA_PATH is important

Comment: yes I did this, if I upload over admin interface everything works

Answer (score 0):

```
def presse(request):
    article = Presse.objects.get(id=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PresseForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=article)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            return redirect('main:presse')
    else:
        form = PresseForm(instance=article)
        return render(request, 'main/presse.html', {
                      'article': article,
                      'form': form
                     })
    return render(request, 'main/presse.html', {
        'article': article,
        'form': form
    })
```

I think the problem is that you are doing the wrong redirection in two out of three cases. Correct code: